# Java - phasing threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm implementing a parallel, performance-critical algorithm with multiple threads. I assign all threads some data to work on. When *all* those threads have finished to work on their data, I assign all threads new data, and the cycle continues. (This is what I refer to as thread "clocking" since it's somewhat similar to CPU clocking.)

What I came up with so far is using a master thread that stores an integer. At the beginning of each cycle, I set the integer to the number of slave threads. When a slave thread is done, it decrements the master thread's integer. Once that integer reaches zero, I start a new cycle.

Is this a good approach, or are there more efficient ways of doing the same thing?

Comment: The correct term is phasing :D

Comment: @Chris Dennett: Thanks, sometimes the hardest part of solving a problem is finding out what to Google for ;)

Comment: ..as long as the decrement is thread-safe.

Comment: See java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

Comment: Yes, `AtomicInteger` is good as it can decrement and get the value all in one transaction (--dec <= 0), stopping race conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off using a [Phaser](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) (if you have Java 7), or [CyclicBarrier](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) for Java 5+.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at the newer classes in the java.util.concurrent package, especially `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.  You might be reinventing the wheel if you haven't looked beyond `java.lang.Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Well. See CyclicBarrier ([JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html))

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use Thread.join(). In you main thread, you call join() on all the threads you are starting. The main thread will wait untill all joined threads are finished.

See for example http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/05/when-to-join-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

An `ExecutorService` can do this for you.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

do {
  List<Callable> tasks = getNextTasksToExecute();
  executor.invokeAll(tasks);
} while (tasks.size() > 0);
```

This will create a thread pool with 10 threads. It will then call `getNextTasksToExecute()` which you should implement yourself to return the next bunch of tasks that need doing. It will execute those tasks in parallel in the thread pool and then keep looping until `getNextTasksToExecute()` returns no more tasks.

Edit:
Code not tested, think there may be a compile error, but you can figure that out.